# Running vue dev server in HTTPS

Tags: ssl, vue.js

Is there an easy way to do this? I've googled and none of the answers worked for me. I need to do this to enable a facebook login which only works through HTTPS. I've generated the SSL certificates however I don't know how to configure the server to enable HTTPS.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the new(er) vue-cli-service then you can run the development server as per https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve

Simply edit your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --https",
    ...
}
```

I was trying to work out how to get Chrome on Android to successfully use the unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure flag, without any luck. At least this allows me to test my vue aplicat

Comment: worked for me. I needed HTTPS to be able to test my app on iOS safari, so by adding the "--https" I can access that now even with a bad certificate

Comment: Mmm, i recieve always the error sockjs.js?9be2:1609 GET https://192.168.0.2:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1626909596955 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in the console after do this

Answer (score 2):

The solution was instead of running the server with `yarn serve`, use `yarn serve --https`

Comment: npm WARN invalid config https-proxy=true npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'